# Combo Box with switch case

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I'm trying to create a combo box that will switch based on a previous combo box. So I created a module off of the first combo box and put this code in there. The first box populates as expected

```
Sub DropDown9_Change()
DropDown14 = ""

Select Case DropDown9
    Case "PIP"
        DropDown14.RowSource = "rsm"
    Case "SAFETY WORKS"
        DropDown14.RowSource = "rsm2"
    Case "ASI"
        DropDown14.RowSource = "rsm"
    Case "Century Glove"
        DropDown14.RowSource = "rsm"

End Select
End Sub
```

I'm thinking that this will only work with a UserForm and not modules.

My question is really how can I get a combobox to switch based on a previous combobox?

Comment: Not sure what is your question.

Comment: How can I get a combobox to switch based on a previous combobox?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you were nearly there:

```
Private Sub DropDown9_Change()
DropDown14.Value = ""
    Select Case DropDown9.Value
        Case "PIP"
            DropDown14.Value = "rsm"
        Case "SAFETY WORKS"
            DropDown14.Value = "rsm2"
        Case "ASI"
            DropDown14.Value = "rsm"
        Case "Century Glove"
            DropDown14.Value = "rsm"
    End Select
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

The following should do the job for Form Control Drop Down boxes on the Sheet:

```
Sub DropDown9_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim CheckDrop As Shape: Set CheckDrop = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 9")
Dim DestinationDrop As Shape: Set DestinationDrop = ws.Shapes("Drop Down 14")
'above declare and set your Sheet and the name of your drop downs
'as long as the Drop Down's have the values in their lists, then the Case below will select the appropriate value
With CheckDrop
        listNew = DestinationDrop.ControlFormat.List
        Select Case .ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.ListIndex)
            Case "PIP"

                If UBound(listNew) > 0 Then
                    For i = 1 To UBound(listNew)
                        If listNew(i) = "rsm" Then DestinationDrop.ControlFormat.ListIndex = i
                    Next i
                End If
            Case "SAFETY WORKS"

                If UBound(listNew) > 0 Then
                    For i = 1 To UBound(listNew)
                        If listNew(i) = "rsm2" Then DestinationDrop.ControlFormat.ListIndex = i
                    Next i
                End If
            Case "ASI"

                If UBound(listNew) > 0 Then
                    For i = 1 To UBound(listNew)
                        If listNew(i) = "rsm" Then DestinationDrop.ControlFormat.ListIndex = i
                    Next i
                End If
            Case "Century Glove"

                If UBound(listNew) > 0 Then
                    For i = 1 To UBound(listNew)
                        If listNew(i) = "rsm" Then DestinationDrop.ControlFormat.ListIndex = i
                    Next i
                End If
        End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so now when I select from the first dropdown (DropDown9), I get an error "cannot run the macro......"

Comment: Are these comboboxes in a Form or on a Sheet, if on a Sheet is it an ActiveX control or a Form Control?

Comment: Form Control on a sheet. I was trying to avoid using this as a form.